# Sudoku Solving Algorithm

Tags: java, sudoku

I have tried writing the algorithm by referring [this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmics_of_Sudoku#Example_of_a_brute_force_Sudoku_solver_.28in_C.29)
But i am getting Error of StackOverFlow.
Help me out to find what is wrong in the program? Is it the recursion part?

```
public void beginSolving(int board[][],int x,int y){
    int i = 1;
    if(unassignedCell(board,x,y)){
        board[x][y] = i;
        if(isValidCell(board,y,x,i)){
            board[x][y] = i;
        }
        if(!isValidCell(board,y,x,i)){
            board[x][y] = 0;
            i++;
        }
    } else { 
        while(x<9){
            beginSolving(board,x++,y);
            if(x==9){
                x = 1;
                beginSolving(board,x,y++);
                if(y==9){

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at the recursive calls: `beginSolving(board,x++,y)`. The `x` and `y` parameters are the same as in the original call (remember that the value of `x++` is the value before it is incremented). Thus it is likely that you enter a never ending recursion.

The `while(x < 9)` will never terminate since whenever `x` reaches 9 it is reset to 1.

The algorithm never tries to set a number other than 1 into the board.

There may be other problems with the code as well, I did not check it in detail.

Comment: I am a complete beginner so if possible can you help me out with getting the solution. Should i make it ++x?

Comment: Yes, `++x` is better.

Comment: @MärmîkŠhâh StackOverflow errors are a great way to practice your debugging skills. You should set a breakpoint at the start of your method and run through your application and see how it works.